# PHP Adjacency List to Nested Array

Tags: php, arrays, nested, hierarchical-data, adjacency-list

I am trying to convert following table data into nested array using PHP. I am almost done but stuck at one point.

```
id  name                    parent
1   Apparel                                                                   
2   Appliances                                                                
46  Apparel                 1                                                 
47  Child Apparel           46                                                
49  Child Apparel 2         47
```

Using this code

```
$cats = array(); // from database

$refs = array();
$rcats = array();

foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    $thisref = &$refs[$cat['id']];

    $thisref['id'] = $cat['id'];
    $thisref['name'] = $cat['name'];
    $thisref['leaf'] = "true";

    if (!$cat['parent']) {
        $rcats[$cat['id']] = &$thisref;
    } else {
        unset($refs[$cat['parent']]['leaf']);
        $refs[$cat['parent']]['items'][$cat['id']] = &$thisref;
    }
}          

print_r(json_encode($rcats));
```

This results into following JSON.

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Apparel",
        "items": {
            "46": {
                "id": "46",
                "name": "Apparel",
                "items": {
                    "47": {
                        "id": "47",
                        "name": "Child Apparel",
                        "items": {
                            "49": {
                                "id": "49",
                                "name": "Child Apparel 2",
                                "leaf": "true"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Appliances",
        "leaf": "true"
    }
}
```

Where as I want the JSON like

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Apparel",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "46",
                "name": "Apparel",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": "47",
                        "name": "Child Apparel",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "id": "49",
                                "name": "Child Apparel 2",
                                "leaf": "true"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Appliances",
        "leaf": "true"
    }
]
```

Comment: could you show us your code portion where you call json_encode?

Comment: It works though when I gave it a thought, it didn't theoretically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I'm assuming you are storing your final results in $refs

```
print_r(json_encode(array_values($rcats)));
```

If you want to take out all the indexes, in your for loop, do `[]` instead of the id:

```
if (!$cat['parent']) {
    $rcats[] = &$thisref;
} else {
    unset($refs[$cat['parent']]['leaf']);
    $refs[$cat['parent']]['items'][] = &$thisref;
}
```

A quick example I throw:

```
<?php

$a = array('1' => array('a' => 3), '2' => array('b' => 4));
echo json_encode($a) . "\n";
echo json_encode(array_values($a)) . "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
{"1":{"a":3},"2":{"b":4}}
[{"a":3},{"b":4}]
```

Comment: Because this is nested array, your solution won't work exactly what I want. It does convert the top level values to array values I see.

Comment: Still your code isn't for nested data. The data I have is in adjacency list.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me what is not working with my code according to your requirement? I'm throwing guesses just now, so ya, need you to tell me what's wrong :)

Comment: $refs[] = &$thisref; doesn't handle child items.

Comment: Hmmm :S, could you post the output you are getting from my last answer?

Comment: This is understood. You're calling $refs[$cat['parent']] when you never save entries with $refs[$cat['id']] at all. Isn't it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9178/discussion-between-andreas-and-umair-ashraf)

Comment: Accept it if you want :p, but that's all I can do

Answer (score 1):

Am i wrong? :p

```
$cats      = array(); // From Database, but i use this
$cats      = array(
    array(
        'id'        => 1,
        'name'      => 'Jakarta',
        'parent'    => NULL
    ),
    array(
        'id'        => 2,
        'name'      => 'Bandung',
        'parent'    => 1
    ),
    array(
        'id'        => 3,
        'name'      => 'Surabaya',
        'parent'    => 1
    ),
    array(
        'id'        => 4,
        'name'      => 'Bali',
        'parent'    => NULL
    ),
    array(
        'id'        => 5,
        'name'      => 'Batam',
        'parent'    => NULL
    ),
);
$refs        = array();
$rcats   = array();

foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    $thisref            = &$refs[$cat['id']];
    $thisref['id']  = $cat['id'];
    $thisref['name']    = $cat['name'];
    $thisref['leaf']    = "true";

    if (!$cat['parent']) {
        $rcats[] = &$thisref;
    } 
    else {
        unset($refs[$cat['parent']]['leaf']);
        $refs[$cat['parent']]['items'][] = &$thisref;
    }
}      

/*
// IF YOU NEED CHANGE TO OBJECT

$rcats = (object)$rcats;
if(isset($rcats->items)){
    $rcats->items = (object)$rcats->items;
}
*/

header('Content-type: application/json');
print_r(json_encode($rcats));
```